# What does `import ev._` for implicit evidence mean, and when should I use it?

Tags: scala, extension-methods, implicit-conversion, typeclass, implicit

the Arithmetic.scala is:

```
package Arithmetic
// The Arithmetic typeclass which implements various arithmetic operations on custom datatypes
abstract class Arithmetic[T <: Data] {
  implicit def cast(t: T): ArithmeticOps[T]
}

abstract class ArithmeticOps[T <: Data](self: T) {
  def *(t: T): T
  def mac(m1: T, m2: T): T // Returns (m1 * m2 + self)
  def +(t: T): T
  ...
}

object Arithmetic {
  implicit object UIntArithmetic extends Arithmetic[UInt] {
    override implicit def cast(self: UInt) = new ArithmeticOps(self) {
      ...
    }  

  implicit object SIntArithmetic extends Arithmetic[SInt] {
    override implicit def cast(self: SInt) = new ArithmeticOps(self) {
      ...
    }
}
```

in another scala file:

```
import Arithmetic._

class PE[T <: Data](inputType: T, ...)(implicit ev: Arithmetic[T]) extends Module {
  import ev._
  ...
}
```

my question is:

1. Can an abstract class has a companion object?(such as the Arithmetic)
2. I know there is some implicit conversion. what makes me confused is that when I use `import Arithmetic._`, what is the `ev` refer to? the companion object or the abstract class?

Comment: 1. I assume it compiles, so the answer is "obviously yes". 2. The `ev` refers to the `implicit ev: Arithmetic[T]` parameter. The `import Arithmetic._` and the `import ev._` have two independent roles in your example: the `import ev._` allows to use the implicit `cast` conversion inside of `PE`, whereas `import Arithmetic._` provides the actual instances for various sub-flavors of integers.

Comment: That upper-case package name `Arithmetic` is confusing, by the way.

Comment: That is weird way to define and implement a typeclass

Comment: @xlgforever If `ev` referred to the companion object it would have a different type: `ev: Arithmetic.type` and not `ev: Arithmetic[T]`

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Why wouldn't you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Not so weird. Looks like a Scala 2 emulation for Scala 3 type class with extension methods `trait Arithmetic[T <: Data] { extension (self: T) { def *(t: T): T; def mac(m1: T, m2: T): T; def +(t: T): T } }`

Comment: @DmytroMitin Well, the answer would have the structure along the lines of [Find `ev` - There it is!](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/FoundX.svg/290px-FoundX.svg.png?20080422195102). I still don't see what's actually being asked, unless it's modified into something with substance, I'd prefer to just close it.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin You shouldn't underestimate the value of trivial for you answers, sometimes :)

Comment: Thanks to all of you. The package name should be lower-case(but my editor AutoCorrects this incorrectly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, regarding whether we can define an object `Arithmetic` if there is already a trait / class `Arithmetic`: yes. There are two independent kinds of names: type-names and value-names. Abstract class declarations and trait declarations such as

```
abstract class Arithmetic[A] // or 
trait Arithmetic[A]
```

introduce a *named type* with name `Arithmetic`. The companion object declaration

```
object Arithmetic
```

introduces a *value name* `Arithmetic`. The type-names and the value-names live in separate realms, and do not collide.

Having a companion object `Foobar` for a trait `Foobar[X]` is quite common if `Foobar[X]` is modeling a typeclass, because the compiler will look for instance definitions preferentially in the `object Foobar`.

---

Second, regarding the various imports:

```
import Arithmetic._
```

is just a package import. Confusingly, because you have a class`Arithmetic.Arithmetic` and object `Arithmetic.Arithmetic`, this brings the class and the object into scope.

On the other hand, this here

```
import ev._
```

says essentially: *"In this block of code, when you need `+` or `*`, go ask the `ev: Arithmetic[T]` how `+` and `*` are defined"*.

How `ev` gets instantiated depends on the type `T` at the instantiation site where `PE[T]` is constructed. If you're constructing

```
val myUInt: UInt = ...
new PE[UInt](myUInt)
```

, you're essentially telling the compiler: *"Dear compiler, I'm lazy, go search for an instance of `Arithmetic[UInt]` in some of the packages that I've imported"*. The compiler will go and see where it can get an `compilerGenerated_ev: Arithmetic[UInt]`, and pass it automatically as the implicit argument:

```
val myUInt: UInt = ...

// : found it in `Arithmetic.UIntArithmetic`
val compilerGenerated_ev: Arithmetic[UInt] = Arithmetic.UIntArithmetic
new PE[UInt](myUInt /* ‍♂️ */)(compilerGenerated_ev /*  */)
```

Then the body inside of `PE[T]`-initializer will take over, import the `*` and `+` from the `compilerGenerated_ev`, and do calculations with that.

---

Here, again, the full example in the refreshed Scala 3 syntax.
It demonstrates how the compiler plugs in two different `Arithmetic[Int]` and `Arithmetic[Double]` instances depending on what you pass to `PE`-constructor.

```
// This is just a package (it's very confusing that
// in your example, the package is also named `Arithmetic`
package arithmetic {

  // This defines what it means that "we can do Arithmetic on carrier set `A`"
  trait Arithmetic[A]:

    // Doing arithmetic on `A` means that we can add and multiply `A`s
    extension (a: A)
      infix def *(other: A): A
      infix def +(other: A): A

  // The companion object of the typeclass `Arithmetic` is one of the first
  // places where the compiler will search for instances of `Arithmetic[A]`
  object Arithmetic {

    // We can do arithmetic with integers
    given Arithmetic[Int] with
      extension (i: Int)
        infix def *(other: Int) = i * other
        infix def +(other: Int) = i + other

    // We can do arithmetic with Doubles
    given Arithmetic[Double] with
      extension (d: Double)
        infix def *(other: Double) = d * other
        infix def +(other: Double) = d + other
   
  }
}

// This import says: 
// "bring `trait Arithmetic[T]` and
// companion `object Arithmetic` into
// scope
import arithmetic._

// This class has the superpower of computing `x * x + x`
// for `x: T`, provided that we can do arithmetic on `T`.
class PE[T](x: T)(using ev: Arithmetic[T]) {
  // This import says:
  // "In the following, when looking for definitions for `+`
  //  and `*`, look inside of the `ev`
  import ev.*

  def foobar: T = x * x + x 
}

@main def example(): Unit = {
  println(PE(42).foobar)    // 1806: Int
  println(PE(0.001).foobar) // 0.001001: Double
}
```

Comment: When `T` is `UInt`, the instance `UIntArithmetic` in  the companion object looks like a subclass of `Arithmetic[UInt]`, and  in `PE` class the `ev` is declared with a type named Arithmetic[UInt], not the subclass `UIntArithmetic` directly. is that work correctly?  Will the compiler match the subclass of `Arithmetic[UInt]` to `ev`?

Comment: @xlgforever That's the whole point: `Arithmetic[UInt]` is a _type_, which is essentially a _query_ telling _"hey, compiler, go find me an instance of `Arithmetic[UInt]` somewhere"_. The `UIntArithmetic` is a _value_ that is found by the compiler as an answer to the query `Arithmetic[UInt]`. It's a search engine / code generator. You specify the desired properties of the code as _types_, it then searches / generates corresponding _code_ that satisfies those properties.

Comment: @Andry Tyukin Oh! You are right, thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!^_^